# Securing Camel CXFRS consumer with SAML

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, saml-2.0

I'm attempting to secure a CXFRS consumer endpoint defined in camel with SAML Web SSO using the cxf SamlRedirectBindingFilter.  Below is the spring XML defining the route/endpoints:

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>

<bean id="stateManager" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.sso.state.EHCacheSPStateManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="cxf"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redirectGetFilter" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.sso.SamlRedirectBindingFilter">
    <property name="idpServiceAddress" value="http://carnold-linux.ptcnet.ptc.com:9093/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO"/>
    <property name="assertionConsumerServiceAddress" value="/racs/sso"/>
    <property name="stateProvider" ref="stateManager"/>
    <property name="addWebAppContext" value="false"/>
</bean>

<camelContext id="camel" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="proxyRoute">
        <from uri="cxfrs://http://0.0.0.0:9092/app?resourceClasses=com.company.FooResource,com.company.BarResource&amp;providers=#redirectGetFilter"/>
    ...rest of route
```

The issue I'm having is that even though I added the SamlRedirectFilter to the providers for the endpoint - it's not redirecting/authenticating.  Any thoughts on what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current camel release version doesn't support to configure the provides from the uri.

You can configure the provider by using the cxf:rsServer just like this

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://0.0.0.0:9092/app"
    >
    <cxf:providers>
       <ref bean="redirectGetFilter"/>
    </cxf:providers>
    <cxf:serviceBeans>
       <ref bean="fooResource"/>
       <ref bean="barResource"/>
    </cxf:serviceBeans>
 </cxf:rsServer>

<bean id="fooResource" class="com.company.FooResource"/>
<bean id="barResource" class="com.company.BarResource"/>

<camelContext id="camel" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="proxyRoute">
        <from uri="cxfrs://bean:rsServer"/>
    ...rest of route
```